# Is the latest version of docker from Amazon on ec2 broken?

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker

As of last night all our new docker deployments started failing because the latest version of docker (docker-1.3.2-1.0.amzn1.x86_64) in the amazon repo fails to start up.

Steps to reproduce are:

```
## Launch instance with default amazon AMI

yum install docker-1.3.2-1.0.amzn1.x86_64
service docker restart

### Get the following error in /var/log/docker
2014/11/26 05:14:16 docker daemon: 1.3.2 c78088f/1.3.2; execdriver: native; graphdriver:
[8f6d7cfb] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
[info] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
docker: relocation error: docker: symbol dm_task_get_info_with_deferred_remove, 
      version Base not defined in file libdevmapper.so.1.02 with link time reference
```

If I downgrade back to docker-1.3.1-1.0.amzn1.x86_64 everything seems to be fine.

Is the AWS package actually broken, or is it just our setup?
Is there a work around other than downgrading?

Comment: I've had terrible luck with amazon's docker.  I grab the latest binary from their website. https://get.docker.io/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-{{version}}

Comment: yum update fices it for me so I am guessing they missed a package dependency. It would be good to know which package did the trick but that will take too long manually

Comment: `yum update` did not fix it for me against epel-testing. Had to resort to pulling a fresh binary `wget https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest -O /usr/bin/docker`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is broken for me too.

Downgrading has been the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

The same error was by me on a centos VM provisioned at my workplace - a yum update resolved it.

I suspect a build was broken but went out, and has been fixed subsequently.

Comment: Yeah found the same thing, Unfortunately we have auto-launched instances therefore updating the entire package set is too slow. We are not able to get our instances up quickly enough in response to load. I will see if someone can track down which package needs to be updated specifically to fix the issue. If no one answers I will accept this as it is technically correct.